# Best way to go about converting java code for android play store for iOS appliction

Tags: ios

Android application is completed. Started learning objective C in order to convert the code and publish on Apple's App Store. Is there a better way to go about converting the code? Thank you in advance

Comment: Hire someone to do that.

Comment: You asked for the best way :) Theres is no good or bad tool for that that I know and even if that would exist then you would have to tweak generated code which is a pain in it self ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1) [J2ObjC](https://github.com/google/j2objc)

I'd suggest this one; it's by google for google and under Apache 2.0 with public code — a promising combo if you ask me.

straight from the readme:

> J2ObjC is an open-source command-line tool from Google that translates
>   Java source code to Objective-C for the iOS (iPhone/iPad) platform.
>   This tool enables Java source to be part of an iOS application's
>   build, as no editing of the generated files is necessary.

It's what google uses to keep a minimal codebase for some of their apps (inbox for one).

This won't relinquish you from *all* responsibility — UI will still be on you — but it will get you about as far as anything else would.

#### 2) [XMLvm](http://xmlvm.org/overview/)

More specifically, [this page](http://xmlvm.org/iphone/). It's open source under the LGPL, and even J2ObjC's site mentions it as a good alternative.

and a snippet from their site

> [mentions of other conversion features]... Yet another
>   transformation allows to cross-compile a Java program to
>   Objective-C to create a native iPhone application.

---

> my two cents: unless your app has some crazy "stuff" going on, the most maintainable solution (certainly for a small team with web experience) would be to get your [java to javascript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#javajvm) and use [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). You're only maintaining a single app and a single ui.